# How to Test the Geo IP

Tags: selenium, ip, geo

hi everyone I have a test site where the page language will Change according to the Country IP so a person in US will view the page in English and a person in Paris views the page in French.. So I need to test, does the Web page Language Change according to the Country's IP. Can anyone have any idea about this Please Help ...

Im using Selenium Webdriver Java for Automation Testing but if you have for Manuel Testing also Share it ...

Thank you

Comment: *a person in Paris views the page in Spanish* - don't they have French anymore?;)

Comment: Why would Paris end up being Spanish?

Comment: isn't Paris in Germany? =O

Comment: hi guy im sorry now i have Changed it to French so can anyone help me on This...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some proxy servers (there are lists of them maintained on the web).